# What are tips for optimizing using LocationManager Android

Tags: android, gps, location

It eats up a lot of battery, but I still want to be able to track location of the device if the app isn't in the foreground.  What are ways to optimize the location manager?

Everytime onLocationChanged is triggered it'll make an API request.  Will it improve the battery that much by having a timer on when the API request can be sent?

Or is there a way to have a low-powered gps mode when the app isn't in the foreground?

Answer (score 0):

If you use google play services to obtain location from either gps or coarse location provider, you can set the frequency of those location updates. What you need to do is detect when your app is put in background and notify your service to update location less frequently.

And when the app comes back you update again to receive more frequent location updates.

You can also change the provider, network location is cheaper battery wise but its less accurate, you could work with network in the background and gps in foreground.

You can use the locationRequest object in the fused location provider to configure these settings.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest

https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html#updates